# How to make a non-transactional Spring test?

Tags: java, spring, testing, transactions

I have this test class:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void add() {
    }
    ...
}


@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
public class AbstractServiceTest  extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
 ...
}
```

All methods `CandidateServiceTest` are *transactional*.

How I can change `CandidateServiceTest` that all its methods were *non-transactional*?

Answer (score 1):

Don't extend `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`. Just use the `@Transactional` annotation as you would do with services:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
public class AbstractServiceTest {

}

@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void add() {
        // non-transactional test
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void transactionalAdd() {
        // transactional test
    }
}
```